# Target Display Mode: how to automate and persist on closing laptop

Tags: imac, macbook-pro, target-display

I have connected my MacBook (Early 2013, OS X 10.9.4) with my iMac (Late 2012, 27 inch, OS X 10.9.4) via a ThunderBolt cable in order to use the iMac screen with my MacBook.

I have two related questions:

(i) Is there a way to automatically mirror the screen without needing to press Command-F2?

(ii) How can I allow screen mirroring to persist when I close my MacBook?

Comment: When you say, "How can I allow screen mirroring to persist when I close my MacBook?", do you mean to move the desktop onto the iMac, or to automatically mirror it when you open the screen again?

Comment: I mean the former: to move the desktop to the iMac.